# - OiJarResourceLoader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: oracle, server

I want to install Oracle server side，When I install the Oracle server on my computer, it appears  - OiJarResourceLoader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsUcF.png)

After clicking OK, the window closes
can someone help me

Comment: Please try `SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en` before you run the installer to get english error messages. It is not very smart to cover the actual log messages.